# 42131 Bulldozer Testing

Tags: technic, building, software

Got to the testing page and everything is working correctly except the left track is going in the opposite direction to the app animation.
Should I start again?

Comment: Thanks - I saw that and have also now rebuilt and the same parts are still moving opposite to the animation so I will continue to build it as they have done - hoping for the best!!! Otherwise, it’s a massive tear down and rebuild!